# Opengl how to scale objects with Orthographic Matrix on window size

Tags: java, opengl

Okay i have a orthographic matrix (left = 0, right = 800, bottom = 0, top = 600, near = -1.0f, far = 1.0f).How to scale the object like for half size 400 width and 300 height.When i scale it it only scales with 0.5f for half size not 400 or 300.

MainGame java

```
package com.engine.base.test;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU;

import com.engine.base.game.Game;
import com.engine.base.game.GameObject;
import com.engine.base.maths.Vector3f;
import com.engine.base.utils.Console;

public class MainGame extends Game{

    public MainGame(int width, int height, String title) {
        super(width, height, title);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateGame() {
        Console.printLog(GLU.gluErrorString(glGetError()));

    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        GameObject object = new GameObject();
        object.getTransformation().Scale2f(400, 300); //Here it only scales from 0.0f to 1.0f
        object.getTransformation().Rotate1f(150);
        //object.getTool().setColor(new Vector3f(0.2f, 1f, 0.5f));
        //object.setAmbientLight(new Vector3f(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f));
        getLevel().addObject(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy(){

    }

}
```

Rectangle java (here is where i write the vertecies and the indices)

```
package com.engine.base.graphicComponents;

import com.engine.base.graphics.Mesh;
import com.engine.base.graphics.Vertex;
import com.engine.base.maths.Vector3f;

public class Rectangle extends Shape{

public Rectangle(float x, float y, float width, float height, Vector3f color)
{
    super(x, y,color);
}

public Rectangle(float x, float y, float width, float height)
{
    super(x, y, new Vector3f(1, 1, 1));
}

public Mesh getMesh(){
    Vertex[] vertecies = new Vertex[]{
        new Vertex(new Vector3f(800, 600, 0)),
        new Vertex(new Vector3f(0, 600, 0)),
        new Vertex(new Vector3f(800, -0, 0)),
        new Vertex(new Vector3f(0, 0, 0))
    };

    int[] indices = new int[]{
        3, 1, 0,
        3, 2, 0
    };
    return new Mesh(vertecies, indices);
}
```

}

Transformation java

```
package com.engine.base.game;

import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector2f;

import com.engine.base.maths.Matrix4f;

public class Transformation {

    private Vector2f pos, scale;
    private float angle = -1;

    public Transformation(){
        pos = new Vector2f(0, 0);
        scale = new Vector2f(1, 1);
        angle = 0;
    }

    public Matrix4f getWorldTransformation(){
        return new Matrix4f().initOrthographic(0, 800, 0, 600, -1.0f, 1.0f).mul(new Matrix4f().initTranslation(pos.getX(), pos.getY(), 0).mul(new Matrix4f().initRotation(angle).mul(new Matrix4f().initScale(scale.getX(), scale.getY(), 0))));
    }

    public void Rotate1f(float angle){
        this.angle = angle;
    }

    public void Scale2f(float x, float y){
        scale = new Vector2f(x, y);
    }

    public void Translate2f(float x, float y){
        pos = new Vector2f(x, y);
    }

    public Vector2f getPos() {
        return pos;
    }

    public void setPos(Vector2f pos) {
        this.pos = pos;
    }

    public Vector2f getScale() {
        return scale;
    }

    public void setScale(Vector2f scale) {
        this.scale = scale;
    }

    public float getAngle() {
        return angle;
    }

    public void setAngle(float angle) {
        this.angle = angle;
    }

}
```

Comment: Pretty hard to see what's going on, best guess is you should pass 0.5f,0.5f to your scale vector, with out seeing how you use your scale vector its hard to say.

Comment: I figured it out.When scaling i should divide the new size with the old size and i will get the scale factor.